# RecyclerView ItemDecoration Does not Draw Vertical Divider Properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-canvas, android-drawable

I couldn't achieve rotated version of horizontal divider in my recyclerview. When i use `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` i need a vertical line between items. I tried to rotate or use different `drawable.xml` but no success.

You can find the code below

```
public class Divider extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private Drawable mDivider;
private int orientation;

public Divider(Context context,int orientation) {
    this.orientation = orientation;
    mDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.line_divider);
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if(orientation == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }else{
        int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
        int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                    .getLayoutParams();

            int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
            int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth();

            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            c.rotate(90, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }

    }
}
```

}

My Drawable

```
 <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:insetTop="2dip"
android:insetBottom="2dip"
android:visible="true" >

<shape
    android:shape="rectangle">

        <size
            android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#cfcfcf" />

 </shape>
```

What should i do?

Comment: You don't need the `rotate()` call. Just set the bounds on the `Drawable`.

Comment: Thank you and can you give an example?

Comment: Yours works just fine after removing that `rotate()` call. I threw it in a generic `RecyclerView` project I happened to have open when I saw your post. I was saying that that's all you need to do, is set the bounds on the `Drawable`, which you've done.

Comment: Problem is, it does not work on me. I tried it without "rotate" but still the line is not vertical^^. Did you do another thing than this?

Comment: Nope. Just commented out the `rotate()` line. Did you remember to add it on the `RecyclerView`? What do you mean by "the line is not vertical"? Can you see a line, but it's just not right? Did you set the correct orientation on both it and the `RecyclerView`?